# Using shapiro.test on multiple columns in a data frame

Tags: r, function, statistics, dataframe

I have a dataframe (let's call it `df`), containing n=100 columns (`C1`, `C2`,..., `C100`) and 50 rows (`R1`, `R2`,...,`R50`). I tested all the column in the data frame to be sure they are numeric. I want to know if the data in each column has a normal distribution using the `shapiro.test()` function.

I am able to do it column by colums using the code :

```
> shapiro.test(df$Cn)
```

or

```
> shapiro.test(df[,c(Cn)])
```

However, when I try to do it on several columns at the same time it doesn't work :

```
> shapiro.test(df[,c(C1:C100)])
```

returns the error :

> Error in `[.data.frame`(x, complete.cases(x)) : undefined columns selected

I would appreciate if anyone could suggest a way to do all the tests at the same time, and eventually storing the results in a new dataframe/matrix/list/vector.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not that I think this is a sensible approach to data analysis, but the underlying issue of applying a function to the columns of a data frame is a general task that can easily be achieved using one of `sapply()` or `lapply()` (or even `apply()`, but for data frames, one of the two earlier-mentioned functions would be best).

Here is an example, using some dummy data:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(Gaussian = rnorm(50), Poisson = rpois(50, 2), 
                 Uniform = runif(50))
```

Now apply the `shapiro.test()` function. We capture the output in a list (given the object returned by this function) so we will use `lapply()`.

```
lshap <- lapply(df, shapiro.test)
lshap[[1]] ## look at the first column results

R> lshap[[1]]

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  X[[1L]]
W = 0.9802, p-value = 0.5611
```

You will need to extract the things you want from these objects, which all have the structure:

```
R> str(lshap[[1]])
List of 4
 $ statistic: Named num 0.98
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "W"
 $ p.value  : num 0.561
 $ method   : chr "Shapiro-Wilk normality test"
 $ data.name: chr "X[[1L]]"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

If you want the `statistic` and `p.value` components of this object for all elements of `lshap`, we will use `sapply()` this time, to nicely arrange the results for us:

```
lres <- sapply(lshap, `[`, c("statistic","p.value"))

R> lres
          Gaussian Poisson Uniform 
statistic 0.9802   0.9371  0.918   
p.value   0.5611   0.01034 0.001998
```

Given that you have 500 of these, I'd transpose `lres`:

```
R> t(lres)
         statistic p.value 
Gaussian 0.9802    0.5611  
Poisson  0.9371    0.01034 
Uniform  0.918     0.001998
```

If you plan on doing anything with the *p*-values from this exercise, I suggest you start thinking about how to correct for multiple comparisons before you shoot yourself in the foot with a 30-cal.

Comment: The final note is brilliant.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. As to what to do with it, well... I need to do multiple correlations between the different columns of this matrix. I would do non-parametric correlations, but my boss is allergic to non-parametric and insists on parametric. I'll see if it's possible to transform the data to obtain normal distribution...

Comment: Whatever you do, you need to correct for doing all these tests. If you did 100 tests and used the usual 0.05 (alpha=0.95) significance level then you are accepting that you'll reject the NULL (H0) on average 5 times in 100 when HO is correct (i.e. you'll find a signif result where none exists). You need to take account of this when doing multiple tests, so look at Bonferroni & Holm adjustments, FDR (false discovery rates) etc. This can be done via `p.adjust()`.

Comment: Yes, good suggestion. However we use correlations mainly for exploratory purposes : finding which variables present the most correlations and then refocus the analysis on this particular variable. Nonetheless I performed FDR to adjust the p values, and compared the 2 sets of results.

Comment: Simple and brilliant example of using the apply family.

Answer (score 6):

To apply some function over rows or columns of a data frame, one uses `apply` family:

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100))    
df.shapiro <- apply(df, 2, shapiro.test)
df.shapiro
$a

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.9895, p-value = 0.6276


$b

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.9854, p-value = 0.3371
```

Note that column names are preserved, and `df.shapiro` is a named list.

Now, if you want, say, a vector of p-values, all you have to do is to extract them from appropriate lists:

```
unlist(lapply(df.shapiro, function(x) x$p.value))
        a         b 
0.6275521 0.3370931
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `do.call` with `rbind` and `lapply` for more simple and compact solution:

```
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100), c = rnorm(100))
do.call(rbind, lapply(df, function(x) shapiro.test(x)[c("statistic", "p.value")]))
#>   statistic p.value    
#> a 0.986224  0.3875904  
#> b 0.9894938 0.6238027
#> c 0.9652532 0.009694794
```